# PHP cURL RESTful request

Tags: php, rest, curl

I have a RESTful server at server.pad.com/authenticate (locally) that takes one parameter and returns JSON. So in Laravel its `authenticate/(:any)`

I'm trying to get data from an ajax request and send it to the server and send back the response. Heres what I've tried...

```
<?php

  $json = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
  $url = 'http://service.pad.com/authenticate';
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  $data = json_encode($json);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  echo json_encode($response);
 ?>
```

Comment: 1) if you have  JSON data in `$_POST['data']` why did you `json_decode` it and `json_encode` it 3 lines after without any modification .? You can directly use `$_POST['data']` 2) As `server.pad.com/authenticate` is supposed to return JSON, why did you `json_encode` the $response` ? May be you should instead `json_decode` it

Comment: What is the current status ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` issue.
Your `$data` is in JSON. You set value with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but not var.
As I can see, $_POST['data'] is in JSON.
In the case the server gets single `data` in JSON try this:

```
$url = 'http://service.pad.com/authenticate';
$curl = curl_init($url);
$postdata = array( 'data' => $_POST['data'] );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata) );

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo json_encode($response);
```

But if the server gets multiple vars, not JSON, try this:

```
$url = 'http://service.pad.com/authenticate';
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
                   http_build_query( json_decode($_POST['data'], true) ) 
           );

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: That looks like what I want but when I do that (tried first and second) it doesn't seem to care what the service actually returns (ive tested the service and it works fine, returns json). When i alert in the javascript what the php is echoing is some giant html string that is so big I can't even close it

Comment: If the server returns JSON you do not need to double-json the response with json_encode($response). just echo $response